# Our azure websites are not available

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Our websites in the west us region are not available. We're trying to access them using our custom domain but we can't access.

When we are using azure website default domain(.azurewebsites.net), we can access our websites. All websites domain configuration and dns redirection are correct. Is there a problem caused by Azure?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We have nothing to do with Azure's availability

Comment: try to visit your site with {site name}.azurewebsites.net to see if you can hit your site. if you can hit your site with the original url, then you might have issue with you domain name or you didn`t config your domain name properly.

Comment: You stated you *can* access your Azure resources by direct `xyz.azurewebsites.net` name, which means your site is up and running. Have you tried doing a lookup on the dns name, to see what it resolves to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are able to access Azure Website using but you are unable to access the same using Custom Domain

```
<WebsiteName>.azurewebsites.net
```

You might want to re-check the steps followed in creating Custom Domain by following the below link
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/